# No consigo eliminar espacio en blanco en imagen

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Estoy colocando una imagen dentro del grid  bootstrap a la derecha y debajo de cada imagen tengo una linea en blanco. La imagen la tengo dentro de un figure y luego  tengo un figcaption el cual le puse position: absolute para dejarlo encima de la imagen miren.
Como elimino ese espacio en blanco???
Nota: uso bordes de color para saber cuanto mide la caja y ver ese espacio

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
                    <aside>
                        <figure>
                            <img src="./img/3.gif" class="img-fluid" width="300px" 
                             height="300px" alt="No se carga" />
                            <figcaption>Ganso</figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </aside>
                </div>
```

css

```
figure{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1);
}

figcaption {
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0.5rem;
  left: 1rem;
}

aside {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgb(109, 109, 109);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar la clase `mb-0` de "Bootstrap" que hace que el "Margin bottom" (Margen de abajo) sea `0`

Lo agregas en `figure` (`<figure class="mb-0">`) como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```css
figure{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1);
}

figcaption {
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0.5rem;
  left: 1rem;
}

aside {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgb(109, 109, 109);
}
```

```html
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <div class="col-md-3">
                    <aside>
                        <figure class="mb-0">
                            <img src="http://c.files.bbci.co.uk/1390A/production/_105383108_ganso2.jpg" class="img-fluid" width="300px" 
                             height="300px" alt="No se carga" />
                            <figcaption>Ganso</figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </aside>
                </div>
```

Si lo quieres hacer por medio del `css` puedes agregar `margin-bottom` y hacerlo `!important` ya que por defecto "Bootstrap" le pone un margen

```
figure{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1);
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Ohh el important y el boostrap funciono!!!! muchas gracias^^